# Will go get command update the package in my local machine

Tags: go

Suppose I download a package using `go get <Import path of package>`. Now after x number of days that package has been updated remotely and now if I run again `go get <Import path of package>` will it be updated on my local too?

Answer (score 12):

The `go get <Import path of package>` command will not update the local copy if there is already a local copy installed.

The [`go get` documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) says:

> The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named packages and their dependencies. By default, get uses the network to check out missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to existing packages.

Run `go get -u <Import path of package>` to get or update the local copy.

Answer (score 0):

No. According to the `go get` documentation it will not. If you want to update a local package you have to use the `-u` flag.

```
$ go help get

......
The -u flag instructs get to use the network to update the named packages
and their dependencies. By default, get uses the network to check out
missing packages but does not use it to look for updates to existing packages.
```

Things change a bit if you use Go modules. Then the `go.mod` file is consulted, but by default it won't fetch the latest version automatically unless you tell it too. For this new behaviour please take a deeper look at the official docs https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#daily-workflow.